# Add prefix and suffix to an input and send it as a command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am adding some rules to an application. I want to make a bash script which would take my input, for example: 'abc', add a prefix 'pqr' and a suffix 'xyz' to the input and send it as a command.

In this case the command to be sent would be `pqrabcxyz` without any spaces as I didn't add them.

The script I am using is

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "ID to be banned: " cmd
"iptables --append INPUT --match string --algo kmp --string '${cmd}' --jump DROP -p udp"
```

Comment: Sample of real input (is it form a file? How are you getting this input?) and expect result would help the most. Any code you have tried will also let us know what your skill level is really like too.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please type in your command" cmd
pqr"${cmd}"xyz
```

Based on the limited information in the question, this should be enough. I hope that @ayush-mishra can be more specific.

Answer edited thanks to reminder by @grgarside

Comment: The Script I am Using is: `#!/bin/bash
read -p "ID to be banned: " cmd
"iptables --append INPUT --match string --algo kmp --string '${cmd}' --jump DROP -p udp"`

Comment: But It is Not working. It Shows no command found

Comment: You have to be root to run `iptables`. Switch to root first with `su` or use `sudo` in a proper way so that `iptables` is invoked as root. You may also need to change `iptables` to `/sbin/iptables`

Comment: Its not working

Comment: @Ayush Don't use `"…"` around the iptables command.

Comment: Thank you @grgarside, I didn't notice this. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below command

### Method1

```
echo "abc" | sed "s/^/pqr/g" | sed "s/$/xyz/g"
```

---

Method2

---

```
#!/bin/bash
j="pqr"
z="xyz"
echo "abc" | sed "s/^/"$j"/g" | sed "s/$/"$z"/g"
```

---